# Is there an app like PingPlotter for HTTP requests?

Tags: web-development, monitoring, http

I'm looking for a macos app that can repeat a HTTP request for a specified URL, from my workstation, at a set interval, and display the response times in a chart. I want to keep this open on screen and monitor it.

PingPlotter does this for ping requests, and allows intervals as low as 1 second.

Pingdom and other uptime-monitoring tools do something similar for cloud-based long-term monitoring, but I am looking for something with a feedback loop that is nearer to live.